# generate a new variable that averages the rows of a group of columns in R

Tags: arrays, r

I'm new to R.  I'm working with a comparative panel dataset with one key variable that is a cross-section of time so that I have to average all of my variables over that time period.

The format of the data is as follows:  rows are country-observations, columns are variable-years.

I've constructed this example:

```
cname<- c("ARGENTINA", "BOLIVIA", "CHILE", "CHINA", "ECUADOR", "EGYPT")
gdp2003<- c(1.5, 2.3, 5.2, 12, 2.3, 3.3)
gdp2004<- c(1.7, 2.2, 4.7, 13.3, 1.7, 1.5)
corrupt2003<- c(5.1, 6.7, 3.4, 5.5, 4.5, 8.7)
corrupt2004<- c(4.5, 5.4, 2.4, 4.5, 5.4, 8.9)
df<- data.frame(cbind(cname, gdp2003, gdp2004, corrupt2003, corrupt2004))
df
```

which generates this output:

```
     cname gdp2003 gdp2004 corrupt2003 corrupt2004
1 ARGENTINA     1.5     1.7         5.1         4.5
2   BOLIVIA     2.3     2.2         6.7         5.4
3     CHILE     5.2     4.7         3.4         2.4
4     CHINA      12    13.3         5.5         4.5
5   ECUADOR     2.3     1.7         4.5         5.4
6     EGYPT     3.3     1.5         8.7         8.9
```

i would like to create a function that can average the column variables by country obs like this:

```
       cname gdp2003 gdp2004 corrupt2003 corrupt2004 new.col.gdp new.col.corrupt
1 ARGENTINA     1.5     1.7         5.1         4.5         1.6             4.8
2   BOLIVIA     2.3     2.2         6.7         5.4        2.25            6.05
3     CHILE     5.2     4.7         3.4         2.4        4.95             2.9
4     CHINA      12    13.3         5.5         4.5       12.65               5
5   ECUADOR     2.3     1.7         4.5         5.4           2            4.95
6     EGYPT     3.3     1.5         8.7         8.9         2.4             8.8
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ?rowMeans. Is that what you're looking for? Also your code has extra parentheses at the end of most lines.

Comment: Be sure your numeric data is not saved as factors first, otherwise you will get an error and no result when trying to apply the answers! Your last data.frame creation line should probably be `df<- data.frame(cname, gdp2003, gdp2004, corrupt2003, corrupt2004)` for things to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to change the command creating the data frame. By using cbind() you converted all of your numeric columns to text (to match the cname column which is text. Then R converted those text columns to factors when you made the data.frame. Also change your data.frame name to DF to avoid any conflicts with function df():

```
DF<- data.frame(cname, gdp2003, gdp2004, corrupt2003, corrupt2004)
vars <-c("gdp","corrupt")
new.cols <- sapply(vars, function(i) rowMeans(DF[, grepl(i, colnames(DF))]))
colnames(new.cols) <- paste0(colnames(new.cols), ".mean")
DF <- data.frame(DF, new.cols)
DF
```

Comment: i knew that dataframe command had changed them to factors but wasn't

Comment: . . . sure how to change them back to numeric.  Regardless, that did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `rowMeans` on select columns

```
df$new.col.gdp <- rowMeans(df[,2:3])
df$new.col.corrupt <- rowMeans(df[,3:4])
```

Now, let's say that you don't really know all of the columns that you want by number but you happen to know that they will all contain something common in the name.  Let's say it's 'gdp'. You could use something like.

```
selectColumns <- grep('gdp', names(df))
df$new.col.gdp <- rowMeans(df[,selectColumns])
```

Comment: `rowMeans` - `M` not `m` - That is all. :-)

Answer (score 2):

While the solutions provided so far will certainly work, I would suggest structuring your data in a different way. You are combining data and field names here: rather than having a field called "gdp2003", you should really just have a field called "gdp" and have another field called "year" and then have a record for gdp were year is 2003. For more on this approach, I would strongly recommend having a read of Hadley Wickham's paper [Tidy Data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html).

Here's how you can modify your approach to set the data up this way:

```
df <- data.frame(country=cname, year=2003, gdp=gdp2003,
                 corrupt=corrupt2003)
df <- rbind(df, data.frame(country=cname, year=2004,
                 gdp=gdp2004, corrupt=corrupt2004))
```

Your data frame should now look like this:

```
     country year  gdp corrupt
1  ARGENTINA 2003  1.5     5.1
2    BOLIVIA 2003  2.3     6.7
3      CHILE 2003  5.2     3.4
4      CHINA 2003 12.0     5.5
5    ECUADOR 2003  2.3     4.5
6      EGYPT 2003  3.3     8.7
7  ARGENTINA 2004  1.7     4.5
8    BOLIVIA 2004  2.2     5.4
9      CHILE 2004  4.7     2.4
10     CHINA 2004 13.3     4.5
11   ECUADOR 2004  1.7     5.4
12     EGYPT 2004  1.5     8.9
```

In this form, you will find it much easier to add data later on and still use your code for calculating averages. One way to do this is to use `by`:

```
by(df[,-(1:2)], df$country, colMeans)
```

which will give you a list of averages:

```
df$country: ARGENTINA
    gdp corrupt 
    1.6     4.8 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$country: BOLIVIA
    gdp corrupt 
   2.25    6.05 

[etc]
```

You can turn this back into a nicer table like this:

```
t(simplify2array(by(df[,-(1:2)], df$country, colMeans)))

            gdp corrupt
ARGENTINA  1.60    4.80
BOLIVIA    2.25    6.05
CHILE      4.95    2.90
CHINA     12.65    5.00
ECUADOR    2.00    4.95
EGYPT      2.40    8.80
```

For even more flexibility when working with tidy data, have a look at the `plyr` package.

```
ddply(df, .(country), summarise, gdp=mean(gdp), corrupt=mean(corrupt))
```

If you want the means and the original results (for instance if you want to calculate differences from means for each year):

```
ddply(df, .(country), transform, gdp.m=mean(gdp), corrupt.m=mean(corrupt))

      country year  gdp corrupt gdp.m corrupt.m
1  ARGENTINA 2003  1.5     5.1  1.60      4.80
2  ARGENTINA 2004  1.7     4.5  1.60      4.80
3    BOLIVIA 2003  2.3     6.7  2.25      6.05
4    BOLIVIA 2004  2.2     5.4  2.25      6.05
5      CHILE 2003  5.2     3.4  4.95      2.90
6      CHILE 2004  4.7     2.4  4.95      2.90
7      CHINA 2003 12.0     5.5 12.65      5.00
8      CHINA 2004 13.3     4.5 12.65      5.00
9    ECUADOR 2003  2.3     4.5  2.00      4.95
10   ECUADOR 2004  1.7     5.4  2.00      4.95
11     EGYPT 2003  3.3     8.7  2.40      8.80
12     EGYPT 2004  1.5     8.9  2.40      8.80
```